# How to apply inclusion and exclusion criteria when data extensions are linked by one to many relationships?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio, database

I have a contacts DE table like this:

**Contacts**

| CustomerID | CustomerName | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alfreds Futterkiste | Germany |
| 2 | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados | Mexico |
| 3 | Antonio Moreno Taquería | Mexico |
| 4 | Around the Horn | UK |
| 5 | Berglunds snabbköp | Sweden |
| 6 | Blauer See Delikatessen | Germany |
| 7 | Blondel père et fils | France |
| 8 | Bólido Comidas preparadas | Spain |

I have another table where all customer's profile attributes are saved,
**Foreignkey** is CustomerID

**Relationship** - one to many ...in profile table, there can be multiple rows for each customer (1 entry /per profile attribute...so a customer with 5 profile attributes will have 5 rows)

**CustomerProfile**

| CustomerID | profile_attribute | Flag | Effective_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DOB | Y | 11/19/2022 |
| 1 | DoNotContact | Y | 10/25/2022 |
| 3 | AddressOnFile | Y | 9/13/2022 |
| 4 | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y | 8/8/2022 |
| 5 | DOB | Y | 11/1/2022 |
| 5 | DoNotContact | Y | 10/2/2022 |
| 5 | SubscriptionPlanHolder | Y | 5/1/2022 |

I have another table where all customer's exclusions are saved,
**Foreignkey** is CustomerID

**Relationship** - one to many ...in exclusion table, there can be multiple rows for each customer (1 entry /per exclusion)

**CustomerExclusion**

| CustomerID | exclusion_type | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BadAddress | Y |
| 1 | Optout | Y |
| 3 | NoCall | Y |
| 4 | BadEmail | Y |
| 5 | BadAddress | Y |

**Desired output:**

**Select all customers from customer table where county is 'Germany' who got profile attribute 'DOB' with flag = Y and profile attribute = 'SubscriptionPlanHolder' and with flag = Y but exclude anyone with 'BadAddress' and exclude anyone with 'Optout'**

So far, I got this and it seems to be giving me right output as long as I am checking only 1 profile attribute.

```
select aud.*
from   (select c.*, prof.profile_attribute, prof.Flag
        from Contacts c
        INNER JOIN CustomerProfile prof
        on prof.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        where c.c_country = 'Germany' and
        prof.profile_attribute = 'DOB' and prof.Flag = 'Y') aud



left outer join
        (select CustomerID from CustomerExclusion
        where exclusion_type in ('BadAddress','Optout') and active_flag = 'Y') exc
on aud.CustomerID = exc.CustomerID       
where exc.CustomerID is null
```

1. Since, I need to select customers who got profile attribute 'DOB' with respective flag = Y AND profile attribute = 'SubscriptionPlanHolder' with respective flag = Y.

How can I apply multiple conditions separated by AND when  there are multiple rows /per profile attribute?

2. I am working with 20mm+ records - is there anything different I can do to optimize the query?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `exists` and `not exists` as they don't expand your result-set like JOINs or APPLYs can.

Also I wouldn't use `c.*` in your query. Column names are cached on save and not refreshed automatically if the DE schema changes.

```sql
select 
  c.* 
from Contacts c
where 
c.c_country = 'Germany' 
and exists (
   select top 1 p.* 
   from CustomerProfile p 
   where p.customerId = c.customerId
   and p.profile_attribute = 'DOB'
   and p.profile_attribute = 'SubscriptionPlanHolder'
   and p.Flag = 'Y'
)
and not exists (
  select top 1 e.*
  from CustomerExclusion e
  where 
  e.customerid = c.customerID
  and e.exclusion_type in ('BadAddress','Optout') 
  and e.active_flag = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: Thank you Adam for your feedback. I got two questions, **(1)**  within EXISTS subquert why you have profile_attribute IN ( ) ? In exclusions it makes sense as it will exclude as long as any ONE is true but for profit goal is to check both flags, not one one. Is it going to check availability of BOTH attributes for a customer? Just asking...do we need group by or something in this case? **(2)** Why do you have Top 1 in both EXISTS and NOT EXISTS? Isn't top 1 will pick random first record only with criteria? Shouldn't we select all records?

Comment: One more question **(3)** If I need to bring some column / field values from CustomerProfile, EXIST (instead of join) won't allow me and i can only bring fields from contacts DE. any way to keep performance good but still be able to pick fields?

Comment: (1) Why would you _not_ want to check for true for _all_ of the specified attributes?  (2) The `top 1` is to limit the result since you only need to check to see if _any_ row meets the criteria.  (3) Your target DE's primary key allows for a one-to-many result?  If you include profile fields with a JOIN, that's what you'd get.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your response. I am aligned on #2 and #3. For #1, I was referring that IN operation to my knowledge act as an OR. So, the logic will look for if customer got profile attribute either DOB or SubscriptionPlanHolder while in requirements I am trying to check for all (_not just any one_). Please let me know if I am missing anything or overlooking something?

Comment: From what I can tell, my query fulfills the criteria you described in your "Desired output" paragraph.  It's basically saying "if the (profile_attribute is DOB _OR_ SubscriptionPlanHolder") _AND_ the flag is true, return the Contact."

Comment: Hi Adam - In desired output, I have 'DOB' _AND_ 'SubscriptionPlanHolder' (in other words.. 'DOB' true and its flag Y AND 'SubscriptionPlanHolder' and its flag Y). Hope this helps

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Adam - Thanks for the update. Using AND seems to be producing 0 results. I even took the sub query part only and this gives 0 results `select top 1 p.* 
   from CustomerProfile p 
   where p.customerId = c.customerId
   and p.profile_attribute = 'DOB'
   and p.profile_attribute = 'SubscriptionPlanHolder'
   and p.Flag = 'Y'`

Comment: My guess is....the issue is coming from the way data is available in the table. The profile_attribute field is only and in query we are trying to select twice with 2 different values. Do you think I need to do some kind of grouping in this case?